# how to remove a character from a line of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the `(` from the HTML below

I have tried the following. I know I'm not using correct syntax

```
jQuery('div li').text().replace('/\(//', '');
jQuery('div li').text().replace('/(/', '');
jQuery('div li').text().replace('\(\', '');
jQuery('div li').text().replace('(', '');
```

HTML

```
<li>This text remains but i need to remove ( <a>from the sentence</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method does not change the string object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.

So you can use the jQuery [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method (assuming you want to keep the `<a>`) to get the string, pass the method a function to do the replacement, and return the modified HTML with:

```js
jQuery('div li').html(function() {
  return jQuery(this).html().replace('(', '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>This text remains but i need to remove ( <a>from the sentence</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have a few that have both "("  and ")"  , how can i remove both instances of ( and ) , while leaving rest of text and a tag in place ?

Comment: @MShack Change the replace to use a regex, `.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')`. The `/g` is the global switch that matches the pattern repeatedly. The `\(` matches the `(` (you need to escape it in a regex). The same for `\)`. And the `|` is the regex OR

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> ```
> var newContent = $('div li').text().replace('(', '');
> $('div li').html(newContent);
> ```

Comment: You lose the anchor this way

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that to replace the text, you need to put the text inside the parenthesis: `text({here})`

```
jQuery('li').text(jQuery('li').text().replace("(", ""))
```

or

```
var str = jQuery('li').text().replace("(", "");
jQuery('li').text(str)
```

See here for more info: https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Comment: this is unwrapping any inner elements in the li , like the "a" tag

Comment: you could change the `text` to use `html` instead. The <a> tag is not considered "text" here. In future posts, could you add that to the requirements?
https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Answer (score 0):

To really be safe about things, you should save your jQuery, and then use each to iterate over each element.

Example:

```
var elems = jQuery('div li');
elems.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text($this.text().replace('/\(//', ''));
});
```

Comment: You lose the anchor this way. Also what's with all the escaping?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning ID or class to element will be better but here is your answer.

```js
$('div li').text($('div li').text().replace("(",""));
```

My recommendation:

```html
<li id="change">This text remains but i need to remove ( <a>from the sentence</a></li>
```

```js
$('#change').text($('#change').text().replace("(",""));
```

Comment: You lose the anchor this way

Comment: I did it with his way.If I were him I'd just use pure js

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this should solve your problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn').click(function(){
     var elt = $("li"),
    result= elt.html().replace(/\(/g, "");
elt.html(result);
     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>This text remains but i need to remove ( 
  <a>from the sentence</a>
</li>
<button id="btn">Remove (</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> `jQuery('div li').text().replace(/([,.(])+/g, '');`